# How to create a 2D table with varying step?

Tags: list-manipulation, syntax

I would like to produce a table with 2 coordinates, where a step for one coordinate depends on the value of another one. I tried to do this in the following way:

```
Step[j_] := Association[{0.01 -> 5, 0.03 -> 10}]
Table1 = Table[{j, k}, {j, 0.01, 0.03, 0.02}, {k, 1, 100, Step[j]}]
```

but I failed. Could you please show me how to do this?

Comment: Also: `Table[{j, k}, {j, 0.01, 0.03, 0.02}, {k, 1, 50, If[j == 0.01, 5, 10]}]`

Comment: And: `Step[j_] := Association[{0.01 -> 5, 0.03 -> 10}][j]` with the rest of your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
step = Association[{0.01 -> 5, 0.03 -> 10}];
Table1 = Table[{j, k}, {j, 0.01, 0.03, 0.02}, {k, 1, 50, step[j]}];

TableForm[Table1, 
    TableDirections -> {Row, Row}, 
    TableHeadings -> {None, None, {"j", "k"}}]
```

[image]